# How can checkbox contionously emit signal?

Tags: qt, checkbox

I want to know is there any way that once the checkbox is checked, it runs the respective code continuously until it is unchecked. In my case, it only runs once. I have read that in button class, there is auto repeat property. But, i didn't find any property related to checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a two staged setup:

1. The checkbox triggers whether a `QTimer` is running or stopped
2. The timer triggers code you want to run

If you currently have something like this

```
connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::clicked, this, &MyClass::someFunction);
```

then you need something like this instead (assuming a C++11 capable environment)

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(checkbox);
timer->setInterval(...); // how quickly you want to repeat
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyClass::someFunction);

connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::toggled, timer,
       [timer] (bool checked) { if (checked) timer->start(); else timer->stop(); });
```

If your environment is not yet C++11 capabable, you will need a receiver slot for the `checked(bool)` signal in `MyClass` and `timer` as a member so it can be accessed in that slot.

Comment: That was a great idea. Now i am using different timers. I want to know either using multiple timers for such pooling is a good practice or not? Moreover, i have started all timers timers with 1ms as timeout delay. What about that?

Comment: You mean multiple timers for multiple checkboxes? I.e. one timer per checkbox?
Not optimal in terms of wake up but easier to understand how things fit together. I would stay with that unless it gives you runtime problems, but 1ms sounds too short of an interval. But again, if your application's runtime behavior is ok, use what works

Comment: Not one timer for each checkbox but using five timers for overall application. Good thing is that it is working. I have made the delay ims because i will be ultimattely using my code on live video feed. Will update on how is it working